# Is the og:image downloaded during a standard browser session? (aka does it affects performance?)

Tags: performance, facebook-opengraph

The facebook documentation for Open Graph Protocol recommends a og:image of 1080x600 minimum (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices/#images).
I'm pondering whether this will affect the performance of my pages on a regular browser visit, and whether i can do anything to optimise both og:image and page load speed.

Answer (score 0):

The image does not get loaded in the browser, so this should not affect performance at all. You can check it out in the networks tab of your browser dev tools (F12).